# Issues with connect to Apache Derby database on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi, derby, javadb

I am working on a Java project where I make apache Derby Database connections in Netbeans with maven. I want to export project to Raspberry PI, but when i am trying to execute jar file i got an error:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused.
```

On local computer database connects normally when I start server manually, if not i got same error.

I understand that i didnt started database server on Raspberry PI, but I can't find where and how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the database server runs on another machine and you can reach it from raspberry pi over network.

It tries to connect to the database server on localhost (Raspberry Pi). Since it is not running on localhost and running on another machine, you need to change the server IP address in order to connect to the database server that runs on other machine.

Check database connection string which has hostname/ip and port. As "dbhost" and "dbport" variables below:

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbhost + 
                ":" + dbport + "/" + dbname;
```

You can check following JDBC tutorial for more details:

[Java Database Connectivity](http://www.java-forums.org/java-tutorial/5407-java-database-connectivity.html)

Comment: No, I want to run Derby database server on localhost (Raspberry Pi)

Comment: Then, you should install and run Derby there before running your program.

Comment: But i can't find out how to do this, that's my problem

Comment: I don't understand. After you install Java to Raspberry Pi, everything else should be same

Comment: But it isn't. In Netbeans i must have additionally created database in services and database server must be started. I don't know how make that step on Raspberry PI. Maybe there is other, easier way to do it?

Comment: Didn't you configured everything on another machine already? What is the difference?

Comment: I didn't configured Derby on Raspberry PI, i can't find working manual to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For information about running the Derby Network Server, see the Derby Admin Guide at https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/adminguide/index.html

Specifically, see https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/adminguide/tadmincbdjhhfd.html